# php list error with my sql values

Tags: php, oracle

Hi guys i'm trying to output my database values in a datalist

this is my code

[image]

my query works:[image]

but my datalist is empty [image]

Comment: You are rushing to accept answer while the answer only answers part of your problem. The answer you accepted does not address all the errors you have, are you gonna come back again with other errors?

Comment: Where's your database tables?

Comment: this is my table http://imgur.com/p0zciR0 in oracle i just have 1 database

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile , he modified the entire question now,  before there were some other code where he had some syntax errors.

Comment: post actual code instead of an image for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
echo "<input id='numero' list='posti1' ><datalist id='posti1'>";
```

instead of

```
echo "<input id="numero" list="posti1" ><datalist id="posti1" >";
```

If you want to use double quotes inside the double quotes then you need to use slash (`\`) before the double quote
i.e,

```
echo "<input id=\"numero\" list=\"posti1\" ><datalist id=\"posti1\">";
```

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is incorrect:

```
echo "<input id="numero" list="posti1" >
      <datalist id="posti1" >";
```

Should be:

```
echo '<input id="numero" list="posti1" >
      <datalist id="posti1">';
```

Because you have double quotes in the string, you can use single quotes to contain it.

Answer (score 0):

That is not only error you having on your script when you done fixing that error you gonna get another error:

bellow are the errors you have:

`echo "<input id="numero" list="posti1" >`
          `<datalist id="posti1" >";`

`echo "<option value="$row[numero]"/>"; // Format for adding options`

They should look like this:

`echo "<input id=\"numero\" list=\"posti1\">`
          `<datalist id=\"posti1\">";`

```
 echo "<option value=\"".$row['numero']."\"/>"; // Format for adding options.
```

Therefore your full code should be:

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = oci_connect('insidedba', 'progetto16', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
echo "<input id=\"numero\" list=\"posti1\">
          <datalist id=\"posti1\">";
$sql = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT NUMERO FROM POSTI WHERE PRENOTAZIONE=NULL");
oci_execute($sql);

foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo "<option value=\"" . $row['numero'] . "\"/>"; // Format for adding options 
}
echo "</datalist>";
?>
```

NB: When you have a double quotes inside double quotes, you will need escape characters.

Some common php escape characters.

> \" -Print the next character as a double quote, not a string closer
>
> \' - Print the next character as a single quote, not a string closer
>
> \n- Print a new line character
>
> \t -Print a tab character
>
> \$ -Print the next character as a dollar, not as part of a variable
>
> \ -Print the next character as a backslash, not an escape character

Comment: Now it works but my form is empty,the query works in sql developer where do u think error is?

Comment: enable error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` paste that in top of your page and come back with the error you getting

Comment: @JonasGarcia i think this is your error :  `echo "<option value="$row[numero]"/>"; // Format for adding options`

what is `$row[numero]` this?

Comment: sorry but i'm new to php i'm just doing for my college exam so i copy and paste the code that i find on internet and edit something

Comment: add this on first line of your page `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);?>` then run your page again and tell me the error you getting

Comment: Ok, I've never worked with oracle before but I believe before you output the results you should also check if you do have results, can u update your question and add your table structure, there's something fishy with your query.

Answer (score 0):

echo `"<input id="`  numero  `"list="`  posti1  `"><datalist id="` posti1 `" >";`

when php try to read your code line , It sees it as above. it thinks only highlighted words are strings and specially those strings aren't connected by a `.`dot it throws the syntax error .

best way to fix this is as to do it according to the above answers .,

`echo '<input id="numero" list="posti1" > <datalist id="posti1">';`